# Rails getting an error '/' undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am find the average 
This what I am trying to do

I have as set of variables which I am taking from db based upon user_id and company_id the variables are And I cannot added then and there because I need to display individual parameter in my show page and I also wanted to display their average
So I am trying to do as below

```
  @r1=company_rating.collect(&:r1)
  @r2=company_rating.collect(&:r2)
  @r3=company_rating.collect(&:r3)
  @r4=company_rating.collect(&:r4)
```

So I am doing it like

```
arr = [@r1,@r2,@r3,®r4] 
@totalaverage= arr.sum.compact /arr.size
My array sample looks like [10,20,30,nil],[nil,nil,nil,nil],[30,40,50,60]
```

And If I have array all Nil then it should show be Nil 
 But I am getting an error undefined method `/' for #  and Why I am doing compact is because I have sum of the nil values in that

So please help how do this.

Comment: Can any one tell me why down votes for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to do this if you're using Rails:

```
@totalaverage = a.flatten.compact.sum.to_f / a.flatten.compact.size if a.flatten.compact.present?
```

This will assign to `@totalaverage` the result or `nil` in case all the values are `nil`.

Comment: First of thank so much for your help I have solved my problem and   can please give me some positive vote Because my account is blocked. My question may be simple for others but as a new  alone learn it will be hard for me to understand. So can you vote me up.

Answer (score 1):

Do as below,which should work :

```
@totalaverage= arr.flat_map(&:compact).inject(:+) /arr.size.to_f
```

Actually `@totalaverage` is an array of array. Where each internal element(array) of `@totalaverage` can have `nil` values also(as you shown). So you need to remove those `nil` entries if any from the internal array of `@totalaverage`. And `arr.map(&:compact)` will do the same job.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you define `arr` as an array of arrays. *@r1*, *@r2* etc. are all arrays and what `[@r1, @r2, ...]` does is just mixing them up in another array. You probably want to **merge** them, not include them in another array:

```
arr = @r1 + @r2 + @r3 + @r4
```

Second, you should call `arr.compact` first, then sum the contents up. Also, I'm not really sure about the `sum` method. I'd use `reduce(&:+)` instead. So, to answer your question, '/' fails because `compact` returns an **Array**, and you're trying to divide an **Array** to a number. This looks better:

```
arr = @r1 + @r2 + @r3 + @r4
@totalaverage = arr.compact.reduce(&:+) / arr.size
```

What `Array#reduce(&:+)` does is to apply the `+` operator between array members and return the value (not an array).

**EDIT:** `arr.sum` **does** work if you're using Ruby on Rails. Otherwise use `arr.reduce(&:+)` instead.

Comment: Thank you Atlast I gotit solved. Can tell also tell how to find an size of array excluding nil's for example if I have an array [3,nil,4,nil,5] then my array size should be 3 how can I get it.

Comment: @user3144005 `[3,nil,4,nil,5].compact.size` will work.

Comment: So in your example it would be ``... / arr.compact.size``.

Comment: @user3144005 You can try my answer too, despite the downvotes. This answer will not work if all the values are `nil`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I did not downvote you. Though I think it's better if you solve the "array of arrays" problem by merging, instead of leaving it for ``flat_map``. Which is a clever method, but I don't think it was in the users intention to have an array of arrays :)

Comment: `arr` is definitely an array of array.`@r1,@r2,@r3,®r4` all are arrays..Now `arr = [@r1,@r2,@r3,®r4]`.. it means `arr` is an array of array.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Sure I will try it thank you and I have voted you also.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I also got downvoted but fixed my answer. I also think @lipanski answer is the best approach but I added an answer in case the OP wants to keep the `reduce` parts. I also voted you btw.

Comment: I have an another here I dont can ask you in this question or but I am asking I am doing an entry into db like this rating_size=company_ratings.collect(&:satisfaction).count
     attrb1= (company_ratings.collect(&:satisfaction).compact.sum.to_f/rating_size) 
    update_attributes(:attrib_satisfaction => attrb1) and it works fine but question if I have nil value it should update nil which I am unable to succed it can any one tell me how to do it